# Jinja2 Multi-level template inheritance issue

Tags: django, python-3.x, templates, jinja2

I have the following three files in a Django App, with the template engine being Jinja2

skeleton.html

```
<head>
    {% block head_content %}
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> {% if page_title %} {{ page_title }} | {% endif %} Bhargavi Books & Stationery </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ static("css/semantic.min.css") }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ static("Icons/font-awesome.min.css") }}">
    {% endblock head_content %}
</head>

<body>
    <div id="navigation">
    {% block navigation %}
        <div class="ui three item menu">
          <a class="active item">Home</a>
          <a class="item">New Bill</a>
          <a class="item">View Bills</a>
        </div>
    {% endblock navigation %}
    </div>

    <div id="frame">
        {% block frame_content %}
            <p> Body content goes here. Body for {{ content_name }}</p>
        {% endblock frame_content %}
    </div>

    <div id="app">
        {% block app_content %}
            <p> APP content goes here. Body for {{ content_name }}</p>
        {% endblock app_content %}
    </div>

    {% block scripts %}
        <script src="{{ static("js/jquery.js") }}"></script>
        <script src=" {{ static("js/semantic.min.js") }} "></script>
    {% endblock scripts %}
</body>
```

base.html

```
{% extends "skeleton.html" %}
{% from "macros/globalmacros.html" import
            SUIIconList,SUISimpleList,
            SUIImageLabel,SUILabel,
            SUIActionInput,SUILabeledInput,SUIInput,
            SUIDimmableActionCard,SUICard,
 %}


{% block frame_content %}
Frame Content
{% endblock frame_content %}

{% block scripts %}

{{ super() }}
<script src=" {{ static("js/globalmacros.js") }} "></script>

{% endblock scripts %}
```

dashboard.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

<div>
{% block body_content %}
Body 3
{% endblock body_content %}
</div>

<div>
{% block app_content %}

DASHBOARD

{% endblock app_content %}
</div>
```

In this setup, Jinja renders everything except the "DASHBOARD" in the final page. However, when I add an empty block in "base.html", like so..

```
{% block app_content %}

App content Goes here...

{% endblock app_content %}
```

In the final template, "DASHBOARD" is printed. Is this some quirk in Jinja? Is this behavior defined in any docs??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your issue: you've got template A, template B (extends template A), and template C (extends template B). There's a block defined in template A, but it's not showing up in the page that uses template C, unless you define that block in template B. If you do that, *then* the block in question shows up.

First: you are correct in your understanding that this is *not* how the Jinja template hierarchy is supposed to work. Second, I did not encounter your issue (found a different one, though), and I have constructed a proof to demonstrate this. Here's what I did (again, using Python 3 and Django 1.11):

```
$ python startproject myapp
```

In the **`myapp/myapp/settings.py`** file, I updated the template engine:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myapp/templates') # hack / should add `myapp` to INSTALLED_APPS instead
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

In **`myapp/myapp/urls.py`**, I created a dummy view function & route:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def home(request):
    return render_to_response('dashboard.html')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home),
]
```

And finally, I established those templates, but I removed the call to import your macros, along with all instances of `static()`.

Here is the **`myapp/myapp/templates/skeleton.html`** file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  {% block head_content %}
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> {% if page_title %} {{ page_title }} | {% endif %} Bhargavi Books & Stationery </title>
  {% endblock head_content %}
</head>

<body>
<div id="navigation">
  {% block navigation %}
    <div class="ui three item menu">
      <a class="active item">Home</a>
      <a class="item">New Bill</a>
      <a class="item">View Bills</a>
    </div>
  {% endblock navigation %}
</div>

<div id="frame">
  {% block frame_content %}
    <p> Body content goes here. Body for {{ content_name }}</p>
  {% endblock frame_content %}
</div>

<div id="app">
  {% block app_content %}
    <p> APP content goes here. Body for {{ content_name }}</p>
  {% endblock app_content %}
</div>

{% block scripts %}
{% endblock scripts %}
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the **`myapp/myapp/base.html`** file:

```
{% extends "skeleton.html" %}

{% block frame_content %}
  Frame Content
{% endblock frame_content %}

{% block scripts %}
  {{ super() }}
{% endblock scripts %}
```

And here is the **`myapp/myapp/templates/dashboard.html`** file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

<div>
  {% block body_content %}
    Body 3
  {% endblock body_content %}
</div>

<div>
  {% block app_content %}
    DASHBOARD
  {% endblock app_content %}
</div>
```

---

**And here is the output, after viewing that page in my browser:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Bhargavi Books & Stationery </title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="navigation">
  <div class="ui three item menu">
    <a class="active item">Home</a>
    <a class="item">New Bill</a>
    <a class="item">View Bills</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="frame">
  Frame Content
</div>

<div id="app">
  DASHBOARD
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Since this all works as expected*, my conclusion is that you might have a problem with the `base.html` template file. Perhaps it's failing to import your macros, and subsequently not behaving correctly? I notice a trailing comma in there, and I'm not sure if that could be problematic or not. I would suggest using the above code as a starting point, and then slowly add back in the parts that I stripped out, and perhaps the problem will become visible/understandable.

*One thing I found odd, that I don't understand: the `body_content` block is completely missing from my output, unless I define that block in the `skeleton.html` template. It doesn't work if I define it in the `base.html` template, which seems wrong to me, because then we're not really *extending* that second template (`base.html`)... so there *does* seem to be something weird there... but I was not able to encounter the original issue you described, so maybe this will be helpful in that particular regards, at least.